# tinymce.min.js:9 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'removed')

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm getthing this error message "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')" when I applied TinyMCE and run in my webpage.

1/ This is error on console log

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4XaC.png)

2/ here is my config timymce

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqX39.png)

Comment: Please provide a relevant code snippet of your problem. It's impossible to help without this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.